# SQLite ef edmx designer in Visual Studio 2013 update 4 for database first targetting .net framework 4

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0, entity-framework-6.1, edmx-designer

I have been trying to get the SQLite install package to work with my setup.I need to target the .Net Framework 4 but it seems like to get design support for Studio 2013 I had to install the SQLite 4.5.1 package.

I spent much time just getting the edmx wizard to display the SQLite connection and it involved a few hacks with the app.config just to get it working in a 4.5.1 targeted project.

I have a edmx model built now and I want to know if I can use this model created in the 4.5.1 class library in a project targeting .net 4. I just copied to entire edmx into a .net 4 console project to test and I keep getting provider related error messages.

I downloaded the pre-compiled package for targeting .net 4 from the System.Data.SQLite site and copied those dll's into my project then referenced those rather than the dll's installed to the GAC from the 2013 4.5.1 install package, so the dll's should be good.

If need be I can post my error messages and a copy of my app.config file, but I am really wanting to know if I can even use a model created in a 4.5.1 targeted project in a .net 4 targeted project. And I would love some help with how to achieve this if it is possible.

Comment: I apologize for that. I am really just trying to get a SQLite ef model to work in a project that needs to target the .Net Framework 4 while using Visual Studio 2013 update 4. I constantly get provider related errors.